# Create a searchable and updatable react website

Tags: json, xml, database, reactjs, search

Which database/xml solution is the most efficient and secure if one is to create the following app:

A website written in React with a search field which searches all cells of a table, and an admin page with a form to add new rows to the table:

A database/a possibility to fetch and store xml/json to the server.

A simple login to ensure that only admin may add additional items to the database/xml sheet?

The information is simply text organised in a table which is searchable.

Comment: pretty much any stack will do. just pick something and try it out!